# Which access_token do I use to upload a video to an iframe based page-tab application?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, file-upload, access-token, iframe-app

I want to let users upload a video to a page that I am admin for. And the application has been added as a tab to this particular page.

Using the example from https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/ resulted in an infinite loop where the page was reloaded every 2 seconds, and no auth_dialog was presented either. Could it be due to the fact that I am page admin?

So this application won't be posting anything to the users wall; it will only use the user_id and liked status of the page.

Which access_token should I use,

1. Ask the user to authorize the app?
2. Use the access_token that was created when the application was added to the page? Will this token never expire?